# Camel route execution priority

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

I'm trying to understand if Camel is able to prioritize a route execution over another one in the same process.

For example, we have :

```
from("cxfrs://restendpoint").routeId("HIGH").log("high priority");
```

and

```
from("file://filestore").routeId("LOW").log("low priority");
```

I want the HIGH route not to be slow down by LOW route. So when a huge file is being processed by the LOW route and a rest call arrives on HIGH route, I want the CPU to give more time to HIGH route.

I'm thinking of doing that by splitting the routes in 2 applications and using Linux process priorities to allocate more time to the HIGH route.

Is there a way to do that with Camel ? Something to play with thread priority for example ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Apache Camel/ActiveMQ priority route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984449/apache-camel-activemq-priority-route) (the intial situation is different, but the solutions are also valid for your use case):

- Use JMS and priorize the queues
- Use a SEDA blocking queue as also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471455/apache-camel-resequencer-with-apache-camel-seda-queue)
- Use a Resequencer

**EDIT:**

As an additional option use an `ExecutorService` with a custom `ThreadFactory` and set the thread priority such as:

```
ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(final Runnable r) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        return thread;
    }
};

ExecutorService exe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3, threadFactory);

from("direct:slow")
    .threads()
    .executorService(exe)
    ...
```

A nice article about Java thread priority can be found [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The solution you describes allow to give priority to a route rather than another. But the question is : if a long treatment (like parsing a very large file) is taking more than 5 minutes and a priority call arrives after the parsing starts, how does one of this solution can help to give more resources to the priority call ?   In my understanding, the solutions allow to sort by priority, but not to allocate more ressources to one route in particular.

Comment: @Thomas I added an `ExecutorService` option

Comment: That seems great ! Thanks for assistance